# EmberJS: When should I use the Torii vs Ember-Simple-Auth?

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth, torii

I'm trying to learn authentication for a web app that I'm writing. All I want is a login and password, and to make sure the user can't write/edit each others posts unless they are logged in.

I'm not sure I fully understand it. But it seems that Torii is better if you need to do Facebook or Google authentication, whereas simple-auth is better for just logging in. Is that correct? Is there other things Torii can do that Simple-Auth can't? Are there things that Simple-Auth can do that Torii can't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, as you can read in [this link](https://www.codementor.io/emberjs/tutorial/ember-simple-auth-torii-fetch-user-data), it makes sense to use both together:

> Simple Auth is more about maintaining session/session events, providing a framework for authenticating a strategy, and authorizing requests. Torii is more about interfacing with these external authentications. So, it’s not as though Simple Auth and Torii could not exist side by side.

Comment: Clear answer. Thank you :)